# Is RewriteMod for WordPress site: site.ro -> site.com/?lang=ro possible?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm not much of a WordPress specialist - is it possible to redirect new domain to the same site, but with `?lang=ro` query parameter so it shows the old site with selected language?

Result I want:

- site.com -> showing the site
- site.ro -> showing the in specified language and maintaining the links as they are on site.com, but while using site.ro

I have also option of using:

- pre-path (site.com/ro/)
- pre-domain (ro.site.com)
  but they will require additional configuration and this plugin is already outdated so I'd rather not change anything in that regard to not break anything.

Comment: "redirect new domain to the old one" - Just clarifying, "new to old", not "old to new"? And this is for every URL - like for like? Is this intended to be temporary? Do these domains point to the same place?

Comment: I have one site. I want both domains to direct to the site, but the new domain should show different language version of the site. It's intended to be non-temporary. Will edit the OG post now

Comment: Ah OK, I think you'll need to do this in WordPress itself, not `.htaccess`. What you describe is not a "redirect", as in an "external HTTP redirect". (To do this using Apache/`.htaccess` you would potentially need to configure the server as a reverse proxy.) This may be better asked on WordPress SE: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: True, will ask there - didn't knew about it before. Thanks